# Pure Django Form Tying User To Submitted Form And View

Tags: django, django-forms

I am unsure how to tie a logged in user to a submitted form using regular Django forms. I see alot of examples using ModelForms but none (that I can tell) without using the ModelForms. In my forms.py im having a hard time figuring out how to add the author field. I cannot just add author = forms.ForeignKey or something like that. Then somehow in my view i need to call the author field to be saved into the database (my below example is my best guess and probably not right with the "tenant_form.author = request.user").

I have a model that looks like this and has a user Foreignkey setup:

```
class AppyModel(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date_time_form_filled = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I have a forms.py:

```
class TenantForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Last Name')
```

I have a views.py

```
@login_required
def tenant_create_form_view(request):
    tenant_form = TenantForm()  
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tenant_form.author = request.user
        tenant_form = TenantForm(request.POST)
        if tenant_form.is_valid():
            print(tenant_form.cleaned_data)
            AppyModel.objects.create(**tenant_form.cleaned_data)

        else:
            print(tenant_form.errors)
    context = {
        'form': tenant_form
    }

    return render(request, 'fill_appy.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add author when the form is valid,

```
tenant_form = TenantForm()  
if request.method == 'POST':
    tenant_form = TenantForm(request.POST)
    if tenant_form.is_valid():
        obj = tenant_form.save(commit=False)
        obj.author = request.user #add author here
        obj.save()
        # .. rest of code
```

Comment: Ive given it a couple of hours of trying different variations to get this to work and the errors I am getting "'TenantForm' object has no attribute 'save'". I think your answer has me almost there just need to figure out where im going wrong to be able to call the "save" method. Thanks for your help and I will continue to pluck away at this until I can figure out where my logic is wrong.

Comment: update: I was able to get it to work with:                                  usr = request.user        AppyModel.objects.create(**tenant_form.cleaned_data, author=usr)                                                                                            If there is any explanation for why the .save() method was not working I would love to figure it out and try it out.